# Using SCRCPY and React-Native at the same time on a linux machine

Tags: android, linux, react-native

I am trying to use scrcpy for mirroring the mobile screen on my Linux machine, to develop a react-native app. But adb does not allow running scrcpy and react-native instance at the same time. It terminates one instance and starts the other one. The documentation for scrcpy states to add an env variable `ADB=/path/to/adb scrcpy`.
I'm not very familiar with Linux environments. Could someone help me with this please? I tried looking this up on the internet, but most of them explain how to do this on a windows environment.

Answer (score 11):

Okay I figured this out myself.
This is what I did.

1. Create a new folder `scrcpy-tools` inside `Android/Sdk`.
2. copy `adb` from `Android/Sdk/platform-tools` into `scrcpy-tools`.
3. open the bashrc file and paste the following at the end of the file.

```
export SCRCPY_TOOLS=${HOME}/Android/Sdk/scrcpy-tools
function scrcpy_run () {
    ADB=$SCRCPY_TOOLS/adb scrcpy
}
```

Save the file. 
Open a new terminal and simply type `scrcpy_run` to start a new adb instance for scrcpy.

We can now run react-native side by side and debug it on the mobile phone.

Comment: I have tried what you mentioned. It is not working.
scrcpy_run commanddoesn't work.Any help would e appreciated. Thanks

Comment: adb file is over 2000 lines long, probably even longer. How do I even scroll down so much?

Comment: correction: 40.000 lines of code, everything in crypted symbols

Comment: Code is to be added in the bashrc file. not adb.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using scrcpy on linux, exactly same behavior like you had.

I just switched to an other application for mirroring screens from the phone, try out Vysor.
You dont have HD resolution but its enough for testing, also it will work without closing either react native or Vysor itself.

Install it like that:

```
sudo apt install vysor
```